# req.file is undefined multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

This is driving my crazy. I've tried to search, but all the solutions being offered aren't working. 
I am trying to create a simple file upload using multer, but can't seem to get it to work since req.file seems to always be undefined.

Any ideas? Completely stumped.. nothing is working it's just coming back as undefined!

app.js

```
var path = require('path'),
routes = require('./routes'),
exphbs = require('express-handlebars'),
express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
moment = require('moment');


module.exports = function(app) {

  app.use(morgan('dev'));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':true}));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  //app.use(multer({ dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload/temp')}));
  app.use(methodOverride());
  app.use(cookieParser('some-secret-value-here'));
  routes(app);//moving the routes to routes folder.

  app.use('/public/', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../public')));
  if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
    app.use(errorHandler());
  }

  app.engine('handlebars', exphbs.create({
      defaultLayout: 'main',
      layoutsDir: app.get('views') + '/layouts',
      partialsDir: [app.get('views') + '/partials'],
      helpers: {
                timeago: function(timestamp) {
                          return     moment(timestamp).startOf('minute').fromNow();
                }
              }
  }).engine);
  app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
      return app;
};
```

Here is my HTML:

```
  <form method="post" action="/images" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="panel-body form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="file">Browse:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="file">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="title">Title:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="description">Description:</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="2"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
          <button type="submit" id="login-btn" class="btn btn-success" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload "></i> Upload Image</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Routes:

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
router = express.Router(),
home = require('../controllers/home'),
image = require('../controllers/image'),
multer = require('multer');

var upload = multer({ dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload/temp')});


module.exports = function(app) {
  router.get('/', home.index);
  router.get('/images/:image_id',  image.index);
  router.post('/images', upload.single('file'), image.create);
  router.post('/images/:image_id/like', image.like);
  router.post('/images/:image_id/comment', image.comment);
  app.use(router);
};
```

Controller:

```
    create: function(req, res) {        
console.log(req.file);
  }
```

Just another note...
Req.body is completely empty... I see it as:
    body {}

I think I've made some progress. I am seeing something for file and body, but it still says it's undefined?
     body: { title: 'fdsfdsa', description: 'fdsafdsa' },
     originalMethod: 'POST',
     secret: 'some-secret-value-here',
     cookies: {},
     signedCookies: {},
     route:
      Route {
        path: '/images',
        stack: [ [Object], [Object] ],
        methods: { post: true } },
     read: [Function],
     file:
      { fieldname: 'file',
        originalname: 'Chrysanthemum2.jpg',
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
        destination: 'C:\testapp\server\public\upload\temp',
        filename: 'fd17765e4cd03268db6757b8cfb21649',
        path:        'C:\testapp\server\public\upload\temp\fd17765e4cd03268db6757b8c
      b21649',
        size: 15973 } }
ypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `upload.single()` (which your code shows), then the result will be in `req.file`, not in `req.files`.  So change this:

```
create: function(req, res) {        
    console.log(req.files);
}
```

to this:

```
create: function(req, res) {        
    console.log(req.file);
}
```

---

Also, if it's this route that you're expecting to use:

```
router.post('/images', image.create);
```

Then, you don't have the `upload()` middleware installed for that route.

Comment: @user1655940 - See what I added to my answer about not having the middleware installed for the route that calls `image.create()`.

Comment: Silly mistake. Just made an update and tested. Still undefined.

Comment: @user1655940 I am having the same issue. I am wondering, did you find a solution to that problem? Not many people answered to the same problem I had. Please update if you did. Thanks